# How can I check that function really get a variable that defined as const?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

Given the following code:

```
template <class Func>
void f(Func func , int* param){
   func(/* how can I send "param" as const "int*" */);
}
```

How can I do it so that if `f` don't get the variable as const - so we will get error ?

Comment: Some minimal code would be handy for an answer to fill in the blank.

Comment: @chris I edited my question (and I added example in order to clarify my question).

Comment: Which one do you want? "Const pointer" or "pointer to const"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that `f` accepts a pointer to const-qualified int you can cast function argument appropriately:

```
f(static_cast<int const *>(param));
```

Alternatively, if you want to make sure that `f` accepts a reference to const-qualified pointer you can add const qualifier to function argument:

```
void f(Func f , int * const param)
```

Comment: I thought about it too, but it's not doing the opposite thing? Namely, `static_cast` don't remove the "const" from param?

Comment: @Software_t It is `const_cast` that removes `const`

Comment: I am sorry, you right. Can you explain if I can do it with `dynamic_cast` in this case or not (and why) ?

Comment: @Software_t: Sure, that would degenerate to a `static_cast` there. Imho, they should have added `no_cast` when they added all the explicit casts, which is enough here.